# Unable to get the exceptions in try catch

Tags: c#, .net, exception, .net-core, worker-service

I have a worker service in .net core 3.1 in my Program.cs i have the below codes

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Handler(ex);
    }
}
```

And also a worker class as below

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{ 
  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken Token)
  {
    
    do
    { 
     if(condition)
     {
      await _test.GetData();
     }
     await Task.Delay(500,Token);
    }
    while (!Token.IsCancellationRequested);

  }
 }
```

If Task.Delay executes first and then any exception occurs in the GetData() method on the second iteration, it is not being captured by the try catch in my Main method. How can i get these exception to be caught in my main method?

Comment: Identify the type of the `Exception` and add it to a new catch block. **Example:**  `try{ ... } catch(ArgumentNullException ane){ ... } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) { ... } catch(Exception exc) { ... }finally { ... } `

Comment: Also, put the most generic `Exception`  at the last position in the bunch of `catch`  blocks like in the examples above.

Comment: Read this article to learn how to manage exception in async context: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/asynchronous-programming-in-C-Sharp-5-0-part-4-exception-handlin/

Comment: @Rivo since OP is already catching `Exception`, they're already catching everything they can - pus the CLR wraps any non-exceptions that are thrown automatically, as exceptions, so... I don't see how that helps

Comment: You really wouldn't want the exception to bubble up to your main method like that. It would crash the app. Instead, you'll need to add a separate try/catch within your background service.

Comment: Note this behavior changes in .NET 6... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/hosting-exception-handling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the expected behavior.

Your catch block in the `Program.cs` file will **only** handle exceptions thrown when **building and starting the .NET core generic host**. That's all. The catch block is not expected to handle exceptions thrown by the registered hosted services during their execution.

If you check the source code for the `BackgroundService` base class you will understand why exceptions thrown by a background service are lost.

At this [line](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5217c21f1e1b119e87d1d5dc2d523baca51ed57a/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L45) you see that your implementation of `ExecuteAsync` is invoked and the
resulting task is stored inside the `_executeTask` field.

Your override of `ExecuteAsync` is an `async` function. When there is an unhandled exception inside of an `async` funcition, the exception is captured by the runtime and placed on the returned `Task`. The exception will be thrown (with its original stacktrace preserved) when the `Task` is awaited, or an api like `Task.Wait()` is called.
Notice that the `_executeTask` Task is not awaited and that the executing thread is not trying to synchronously wait for the task completion by calling the `Task.Wait()` method. So, there is no chance to observe exceptions coming from that `Task`.

There is only one possibility to observe an exception coming from your implementation of `ExecuteAsync`. If an exception occurs **before** the **very first** `await` instruction, then the method execution completes synchronously and the returned Task will have the `IsCompleted` property set to true and its `Status` will be `Faulted`. In that case, the `_executeTask` task will be returned to the calling code (see this [line](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5217c21f1e1b119e87d1d5dc2d523baca51ed57a/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L50)).

The calling code, which is basically the code starting the .NET core generic host, will get back a faulted task and will detect the error occurred while starting the background service by awaiting the task itself. At that point, the exception coming from the `ExecuteAsync` method will be rethrown and the catch block in your Program.cs will handle the exception.

If any exception occurs inside of `ExecuteAsync` **after** the first await instruction, there is no way for the .NET core generic host to observe the exception itself. Those exceptions will result in silent failures. You can find more details on this by reading [this great blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-silent-failure.html).

As pointed out by a comment to your question, **this behavior has been changed in .NET 6**, as you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/hosting-exception-handling). To put it briefly, the default behaviour in .NET 6 is logging any unhandled exception coming from a background service and stopping the Host, so that you are aware of the problem and you have a chance to fix your code and investigate why it is throwing exceptions.